# Dependency errors while running apt-get -f install

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, apt

I was having issues with `/boot` being full and trying to run `apt-get -f install`. Now that I have cleared out some space in `/boot` I am getting the following dependency errors.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-server
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-server
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 379 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,732 B of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-server:
 linux-server depends on linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.37.44); however:
  Version of linux-image-server on system is 3.2.0.59.70.
 linux-server depends on linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.37.44); however:
  Version of linux-headers-server on system is 3.2.0.59.70.
dpkg: error processing linux-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have you already tried to run `apt-get clean` before attempting to upgrade?

Comment: I have. No luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

Ran these:

```
$ wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/linux-server_3.2.0.59.70_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i linux-server_3.2.0.59.70_amd64.deb
```